# Substituting the expression of a lower order derivative in the expression for the higher order derivative

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations

I have the following differential equation:

[image: dy/dx = sin(x+y)/x]

I'm trying to find the second derivative of y with respect to x. The expected result is as follows:

[image: second derivative of y wrt x]

I'm trying to use sympy to give me the above expression. This is what I've tried:

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
y = Function('y')


#initial value condition: y(1) = 0.5

# first derivative represented as d1 

d1 = sin(x+y(x))/x

# second derivative represented as d2

d2 = diff(d1,x)
```

The result for d2 is:

[image: d2]

This is where I'm stuck; how do I substitute the (d/dx)(y(x)) term with the expression d1?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subs to substitute for the derivative:

```
In [13]: d1.diff(x).subs(y(x).diff(x), d1)
Out[13]: 
⎛    sin(x + y(x))⎞                              
⎜1 + ─────────────⎟⋅cos(x + y(x))                
⎝          x      ⎠                 sin(x + y(x))
───────────────────────────────── - ─────────────
                x                          2     
                                          x
```